# Using social in custom suite links menus

Tags: list-template, suite-links

I'm working on building some custom menus within the suite link bar which will be used to display recent social posts, etc. For example I have a menu that will show your last five mentions along with the social posts within which they were included.  I wanted to get some ideas on the best way to approach this.

I have built the menu server-side using an override of the MySuiteLinksUserControl and injecting the new menus through an override of the Render method such as in this article:

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/

My plan initially was to inject server and client code to run the menu pulling the mention data using the SPSocialFeedManager.  But after getting into this a bit, I'm wondering if I can instead place a search web part within the menu and use custom templates to tweak the look if the menu items, or use an item template without the web part if that's possible.

Has anyone attempted anything like this or have thoughts based on your experience?  Thanks!